# Android lost of check state after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-viewholder

Whenever scrolling up and down, I lose check state of checkbox.

I can't solve this problem for two days......

Please help me

Here is my code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    context = parent.getContext();

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (view == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_llistview, parent, false);

        holder.img_view = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_imageView);
        holder.txt_view = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_textView);
        holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

    }

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(check_flag_arr[position]);

    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                check_flag_arr[position] = isChecked;
            else {
                check_flag_arr[position] = isChecked;
            }
        }
    });

    file_path = list_item.get(position).getFile_path();
    Bitmap showImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);

    holder.img_view.setImageBitmap(showImage);

    list_contents = file_path.substring(45, 65);
    holder.txt_view.setText(list_contents);

    return view;
}
```

And detail explanation will be a great pleasure to me.

I must solve this problem.

Thanks for watching my post.

Comment: Your if and else are doing the same thing. So it becomes redundant. This is not the cause of your issue but just wanted to let you know. if (isChecked) {

                check_flag_arr[position] = isChecked;
            else {
                check_flag_arr[position] = isChecked;
            }

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I know that already. That's for readability to me. My original code has different statements in if and else respectively.

Comment: @ Na Jun Yeop Check my answer below. That should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll, setOnCheckedChangeListener is called. So to handle that in get view you need to do the below -

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.checkbox.setChecked(_songs.get(position).isSelected());
```

You first need to set onchecked null so that on scroll when view is getting populated and you are assigning views, you don't call the onCheckedListener.

And then you need to call OnCheckedChangeListener

```
 holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                     check_flag_arr[position] = true;
                } else {
                    check_flag_arr[position] = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I set null on onClickListener first and then set check value. After that I called setOnClickListener. Am I doing right??

Comment: I can't understand mechanism. I store check value whenever onClickListener is called. And then when getView is called again, I set check value as I stored before. What wrong?

Comment: I solved!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Thanks a lot. If I don't set on OncheckedChangedListener null, next recycled view get previous check value? Is that the reason of setting null???

Comment: So the reason for setting it null is in your recyclerview when you try to set the old value in getView method programmatically, it will still call check change listener so your code won't work as expected as you want to call it only when someone taps on it. Every scroll will do the same thing. Hence we temporarily disable it and set value and then enable it again.

Comment: You really saved my time. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you scroll `setOnCheckedChangeListener` is called.

Removing `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and implements `setOnClickListener`

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                         check_flag_arr[position] = true;
                    } else {
                        check_flag_arr[position] = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Changed better!! Thanks but it's not working properly. What is the problem??